# how to call css file for single pages

Tags: css

When i assign a class to a specific table, will it be effected by other CSS commands?

Comment: Target the table or span by selecting them as you would any element, `table{...}` or `span{...}`. If you only want to target one, either give it an ID or create a specific selector to select that element. Otherwise give them a class.

Comment: what was percentage of CSS files in that they cause late loading?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: i meant, i think enlarging of a CSS file doesn't cause late loading?

Comment: Enlarging anything (images, HTML, JavaScript, CSS..) will increase the load time. But what you're talking about would be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1):

you could add a body class and then apply unique per page styles.

Comment: what was percentage of CSS files in that they cause late loading?

Comment: i think enlarging of a CSS file doesn't cause late loading?

Comment: no, it won't. Looking at the other answers here, I think i have your question confused. You just want to apply styles to html elements. In which case you should just use classes and add new styles to your css file.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to target the elements you want to style:

```
<td class="big">
```

CSS:

```
.big {
    font-size:20px;
}
```